# How to create a BinaryOperator to add up BigInteger

Tags: java, addition, biginteger, binary-operators

I want to create a `BinaryOperator<BigInteger> biOp` in order to add up `BigInteger` values. For example, I will have a huge list or array of different `BigInteger` values and I want to add them all up using a loop and the `biOp`.

The result for e.g. two values should look something like this:

```
System.out.println(biOp.apply(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE));
// outputs 2
```

How do I create or initialize `biOp` properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a method reference to [`BigInteger::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add-java.math.BigInteger-):

```java
BinaryOperator<BigInteger> binOp = BigInteger::add;
```

This works because when you use the class name to create a method reference to an instance method (i.e. not a `static` method), the `apply` method will take an extra parameter for the instance to call the method on. So although the `add` method takes one `BigInteger` parameter, this method reference takes two `BigInteger` parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I got it!